# IJCADがアイドル状態か否かを知りたい

Tags: ijcad, vb.net

IJCAD2019 と VB.NET を使っています。

画面である操作が終わった時点で `SendCommand` を送ろうとしています。操作が終わったか否かを判別するのに `GetGcadState` を使ってみたのですが、以下のコードでは常に `False` です。

```
if IJCAD.GetGcadState.Equals(True) Then
```

`GetGcadState` で判別できるならその使い方を、判別できないなら別の方法を教えて頂きたいのです。よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0):

ヘルプを見る限りだとCOMならGCadState.IsQuiescentで判別するんじゃないでしょうか？
IJCADがGcadApplicationオブジェクトだとすると、下記のようになるかと思います。

```
if IJCAD.GetGcadState.IsQuiescent Then
```

Comment: 判別できました。これで前へ進めます。助かりました